# 2013 Nissan Rogue USB audio not working with iPhone 6 with iOS 8.1.1

Tags: nissan, audio

I have a 2013 Nissan Rogue with the in-dash entertainment system (not the new connect system). Since I updated my iPhone to iOS 8.1, the USB audio hasn't connected reliably. When I first updated to 8.1.1, it worked for one afternoon, but then it went back to either not connecting at all or connecting for about a second before showing an error on the car screen and disconnecting.

Does anyone know if it's possible to fix this via a firmware update? Can you even update the car audio firmware on an old Nissan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue with my Nissan Rogue 2011.

This listed below will fix it...

1) Go to General > Restrictions > Carplay -- Make sure Carplay is DISABLED. (The new IOS 8  enables this on default)

2) Go to General > Reset > Reset Network Settings

Apple's stupid Carplay feature nearly ruined everything. Disable it and it will work flawlessly again with bluetooth and USB music. You're welcome.

Comment: Is the reset network settings really necessary? That's kinda a pain to type in all of the wifi networks saved in there again.

Comment: Yes. It's necessary if you want it to work with your car. Disable Carplay first though.

Comment: Did this Work? My Iphone doesn't have the Carplay under the Restrictions menu? I have the 5c with IOS 8.1.1

Comment: Look again... CarPlay is on iPhone 5, 5c, 5s, 6, and 6 plus. https://www.apple.com/ios/carplay/ By the way, been using my iPhone 6 non-stop in my Nissan Rogue since this fix. No issues at all now.

Comment: Ok. I just upgraded to ios 8.1.3 and lo and behold... my nissan rogue stereo is working fine with it. Did Apple fix it? Not sure.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been so annoyed that I can't listen to Pandora radio in my Juke. It shows all the songs on the screen but no sound and "This device is not compatible with this IPhone" error all the time. I have the IPhone 6 Plus